# How do I work with QT Pro files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

I'm a first-year university student currently using Visual Studio for C++ programming. My new lecturer uses QT Creator but I don't know how to import the files for use in Visual Studio. I installed QT Visual Tools with the hope that it will help me but the `vcproj` file it produces is just giving me errors (I'm using the latest version and my VS Community version is up to date as well). If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

Errors:

> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(20,5): error C2065:
> 'uint': undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(20,10): error C2146:
> syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'n'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(20,10): error C2065:
> 'n': undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,9): error C2065:
> 'uint': undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,14): error C2146:
> syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'i'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,16): error C2143:
> syntax error: missing ';' before '='
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,16): error C2143:
> syntax error: missing ')' before '='
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,16): error C2059:
> syntax error: '='
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,21): error C2065:
> 'i': undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,30): error C2065:
> 'i': undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(23,31): error C2059:
> syntax error: ')'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(24,18): error C2065:
> 'i': undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(24,32): error C2065:
> 'i': undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(24,36): error C2059:
> syntax error: ';'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(27,1): error C2059:
> syntax error: '}'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\important_functions.cpp(27,1): error C2143:
> syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,13): error C2065: 'uint':
> undeclared identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,18): error C2146: syntax error:
> missing ';' before identifier 'i'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,20): error C2143: syntax error:
> missing ';' before '='
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,20): error C2143: syntax error:
> missing ')' before '='
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,20): error C2059: syntax error:
> '='
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,25): error C2065: 'i': undeclared
> identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,44): error C2065: 'i': undeclared
> identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(34,45): error C2059: syntax error:
> ')'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(35,13): error C2059: syntax error:
> 'do'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(35,13): error C2143: syntax error:
> missing ';' before '{'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(35,13): error C2065: 'i': undeclared
> identifier
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(38,5): error C2059: syntax error:
> 'if'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(38,51): error C2143: syntax error:
> missing ';' before '{'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(38,51): error C2447: '{': missing
> function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(46,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
>
> 1>C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Documents\C++ projects\COMS
> 1017\lab1-2020\myTests\tests.cpp(46,1): error C2143: syntax error:
> missing ';' before '}'

Comment: You could use the Qt Visual Studiio addon

Comment: Recreate the project files as CMake, which Visual Studio supports natively. CMake's Qt support is top-notch.

Comment: ***the vcproj file it produces is just giving me errors*** That may be fixable but no one can help fix errors they can't see.

Comment: Those errors don't appear to be caused by the pro file. I think they can be fixed in the code.

Comment: ***'uint': undeclared identifier*** [https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552116/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552116/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm thanks

I tried to fix that error by adding this to the cpp file but now i'm getting 3 errors about unresolved externals
#ifndef uint
#define uint unsigned int
#endif

Comment: You may want to use `using uint = unsigned int;` instead of the `#ifndef uint #define uint unsigned int #endif `. As for the unresolved externals you probably have to show code or consult this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for the help. I asked my lecturer about it and he said I should just make a new project and manually add in each source file and header file without worrying about the pro file. After I used the definition with the hashtags it worked but thanks for bringing the unsigned int error to my attention. Will definitely remember the **uint = unsigned int** thing