# What does `uint` means in c++ while the declaration of a variable in class?

Tags: c++

What does `uint` means in c++ while the declaration of a variable in class?

See [here](https://github.com/mhubii/ppo_libtorch/blob/acb7165832dab8155607e030293655c0c1c89821/TrainPPO.cpp#L22) for the referance.

Is it part of a c++ library such as `eigen/core`?

Does that mean unassigned int?

I searched on google but could not find anything concrete.

Comment: It's short (alias) for `unsigned int;`

Comment: The first thing I find when I google "C++ uint" is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552094/c-uint-unsigned-int-int) which seems to cover it pretty well.

Comment: If you find yourself wanting define some of these `uint`s for your own uses, C++ has [had a whole array of them since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). We stole them from C99. Bit late to the game, but at least we played.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552094/c-uint-unsigned-int-int#:~:text=C%2B%2B%20defines%20no%20such%20type,int%20though%20or%20something%20else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means whatever the author decided it means!

`uint` is not part of C++, so it must come from one of the libraries used by that code. Some Googling tells us that it is indeed Eigen.

By convention, it's an **u**nsigned **int**eger type, probably one without a fixed width, so `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

The `u` in `uint` stands for *unsigned*, so `uint` is an `unsigned int`, whose value will be >= 0.

Comment: This is a reasonable guess, but it is by no means guaranteed to be correct. See the other answers for more details.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ there isn't any type defined as `uint` but it must be a typedef of your library that you're using and it's intuitive that `u` prefix before an int means unsigned integer example `uint8_t`, `uint32_t` etc.

here is how it might be defined

```c
typedef unsigned int unit;
```